# Include input file name in output option

Tags: linux, pdftk

I'm trying to burst multiple files in one go and would like to include the input filename and page number as the output. Something like:

pdftk *.pdf burst output source_filename.%2d.pdf

Any ideas.

If I do

```
pdftk *.pdf burst
```

I just get an error "Input errors, so no output created."

Answer (score 1):

After more googling and experimentation this works:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdftk "$file" burst output "${file%.pdf}-%02d.pdf"; done
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).